# Install TA-lib issue || .whl is not a valid wheel filename, || looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, ta-lib

I am having trouble installing a wheel file via pip.

I am using Windows 11
and my python version : 3.12.0
I downloaded "TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp310-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl" because I couldn't find the file in my version and I get an error when I try to install it.

I open my command prompt
write the following in the prompt

```
C:\Users\Gokhan>pip install TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
```

Then I get this message:

```
WARNING: Requirement 'TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

I don't know what to do, and I need your help.

I tried to do it by downloading many different versions, but I got the same error every time.

Then when I run "C:\Users\Gokhan>pip install ta-lib" in my terminal despite this error:

```
Collecting ta-lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.28.tar.gz (357 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\türesin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ta-lib) (1.24.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: ta-lib
  Building wheel for ta-lib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for ta-lib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      <string>:77: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\talib
      copying talib\abstract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\talib
      copying talib\deprecated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\talib
      copying talib\stream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\talib
      copying talib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\talib
      running build_ext
      building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ta-lib
Failed to build ta-lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ta-lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I got this problem.

Comment: "TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑ **cp310** ‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl" but "build\lib.win-amd64- **cpython-311**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the TA-Lib already installed. To install on your windows PC:

> Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and unzip to C:\ta-lib.
> This is a 32-bit binary release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:

- Download and Unzip ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip
- Move the Unzipped Folder ta-lib to C:\
- Download and Install Visual Studio Community 2015 or later (Remember to Select [Visual C++] Feature)
- Build TA-Lib Library
  (From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt];
  Move to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc;
  Build the Library nmake)
  You might also try these unofficial windows binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)

For `pip install TA-Lib`, please note that the supported programming Languages are:
Cython, Python 2.7, 3.3 - 3.11. Your python version (3.12.0) is not currently supported. Please see [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) for more information.